# SalesForce get list of Contracts for Account

Tags: php, soap, salesforce, soql

My php client connects to salesforce using their SOAP API ( partner.wsdl ). After getting a list of Accounts, I also want a list of all the Contracts for each Account. Since SOQL doesn't allow join statements, the only way I see is to first get a list of ALL the Contracts, then manually filter down to the Contracts associated with a particular Account.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938957/getting-current-product-list-for-an-account-in-salesforce) is similar, but no answer presents a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple options, first you can get all contacts ascoicated with any account with

```
select id, name ... from contact where accountId != null
```

if you have a one or a small numer of accounts that you want contacts for you can do

```
select id,name from contact where accountId in ('id1','id2','id3')
```

or, if you want to get contact data when you get account data, you can do

```
select id,name, (select id,name from contacts) from account
```

or, if you have a complex account query and you want just the contacts for that in a separate query, you can do

```
select id,name from contact where accountId in (select id from account where ....)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually querying contRact from account.
I've never seen syntax like this `select id, name, (select id, accountid from contract) from account` before.